# Why doesn't the Go compiler treat non-declared variable as error?

Tags: go

I've been writing a test program to assist in learning Go. While doing so, I've encountered a few instances where I thought the compiler should have detected an error. I've encountered another similar situation, so I thought I should ask why this situation is not treated as an error.

Example situation :

```
if oError = rwfile.WriteLines(asParams, sParamsFilename); oError != nil {
    fmt.Printf("Error on write to file Params. Error = %s\n", oError)
} else {
    println("Params file write OK")
}
```

In the example above, whether or not the variable "oError" is declared, the compiler does not indicate an error. It also works if the line contains the following when the variable is not declared (as expected):

```
if oError := rwfile.WriteLines(asParams, sParamsFilename); oError != nil {
```

If I declare the variable "oError", then ":=" does not work (as expected).

"rwfile" is a package that I have written, and the function in question starts as follows:

```
func WriteLines(asBuff []string, sFilename string) error { // write text file
```

If I create an error with the write of the file, and use "=" without declaring the variable "oError", the program works correctly and detects the non-nil "oError" variable.

So, why is use of "=" in the above not treated as an error when oError is not declared a variable?

The Go version is go1.1.2 Windows/386.

Comment: I feel like the title of this question should be changed, as it's misleading in it's current form. Any suggestions for a better title?

Comment: @TimothyJones: I think the title is fine; it reflects the OP's understanding at the time he asked the question, which means it probably reflects the understanding of the people who, when searching on Stack Overflow or Google, are most likely to find this question useful.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This means that you have an variable named `oError` elsewhere in the package. (Note that this variable need not be in the same file; it could be in a different file with the same package clause.) So, when you use `oError = ...`, you're assigning a value to that package variable, and when you use `oError := ...`, you're declaring a local variable that hides the package variable. (Per the specification, "An identifier declared in a block may be redeclared in an inner block. While the identifier of the inner declaration is in scope, it denotes the entity declared by the inner declaration." [[link](http://golang.org/ref/spec#Declarations_and_scope)])

If you try a different identifier, a unique one, you should see that the compiler indeed complains.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I'll have to study the spec a little to understand. I presumed that the only variables visible to a function in a program/package that were declared outside of the function, were global variables which I presumed were variables declared above this "main" function. I guess what I need to understand in Go is just what is an "inner block" (I thought I knew). When I hopefully understand why a function is considered an "inner block" I'll hopefully understand which "oError" variable is being used that is external to the function in question. I'm a little surprized.

Comment: Re: "[...] which I presumed were variables declared above this 'main' function": Not necessarily *above*. When a variable is declared inside a function, its scope begins at its point of declaration, but when it's declared at top level, its scope is the *entire* package: order no longer matters.

Comment: Re: "[...] why a function is considered an 'inner block' [...]": The spec uses the term "block" a bit broadly. The two relevant "blocks" here are the *package block* (i.e., all the code in the package, which includes one or more entire files) and the function body (which looks like any other normal block, `{ ... }`). The latter occurs inside the former, so in this context, it's an "inner block".

Comment: My faith in Go is restored. The program in question is fairly large > 2k lines. With respect to one function, I had by mistake declared the variables above the function declaration. The first time I searched to determine what the problem was, I didn't notice that fact. All is now as it should be.

Answer (score 2):

It's unrelated to the actual question, but `go fmt` can really help with tracking errant stuff in a big program.

Also, following the style guidelines really helps: use terse code styles (no hungarian variable names! took me ages to get used to short names) and short files: a 2Kloc file is probably too big. It's massively worth taking a wander through the standard library source code to see what good Go code looks like

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion - use terse code styles. Old habits die hard. I'm open to change, however after spending much time maintaining large programs with variable-names without meaning, I developed what I considered at the time was maintainable code. I do not think you will ever convince me to split large programs up. After looking at some that have done that, I found it a jigsaw puzzle. While I definitely agree that small programs are easier to maintain, I don't think it necessarily follows that splitting a large program up into multiple files necessarily makes it easier.

Comment: Getting back to the variable names. Why is it that the language-developers spend so much time funding meaningful names for functions etc., and yet people use cryptic variable names in programs? I believe that I'm a minimalist with regard to lines of code that are necessary. However, my main focus has always been on maintainability. Sometimes I will actually add a line or 2 to make a program more readable. I accept that using a coding-style that only I use will not help maintainability. However, I haven't yet finalized a coding style. Your suggestions are welcome and I'll try Go fmt.

Comment: You sound like me 6 months ago :) I had exactly the same answers to the same points, and I've spent 15+ years telling trainees to use meaningful variable names.
I now treat go files like I treated classes in C#/Java. Each file contains a bunch of related funcs/structs. I really try to avoid using variables that have scope outside the file they're in, and try to keep the files small. Go is so expressive that it's actually easy to write small, focused funcs, and I've found that it's improved my productivity to do this. If a func is over 20-25 lines max I try and break it up.

Comment: Try it yourself and see if it helps you :)

Comment: Ok, thanks for the advice. I think I need to "master" the language a bit more before changing my coding-style. With regard to scope, no problem there.